# Entity Framework Code First Foreign Key Problems

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to use EF Code First on an existing database. I first tried some of the reverse-engineering tools, but I ran into problems with that, so at the moment I am trying to hand-code some of the classes. I am having some trouble getting some of the foreign key relationships set up. Consider two tables. The first is called LocaleValueLookup:

```
public class LocaleValueLookup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
}
```

This table provides an Id for multi-language text held in a different table (that other table is not important for the purposes of this question). The second table is called SectionType, and it has an optional FK to LocaleValueLookup:

```
public class SectionType
{
    public int EnumId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? DefaultSectionTextLocaleValueLookupId { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public LocaleValueLookup DefaultSectionTextLocaleValueLookup { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried various things, including adding a [ForeignKey] attribute to the SectionType.LocaleValueLookup property, and various incantations in the DbContext.OnModelCreating() override, but **when I query the DbContext, I can't get the DefaultSectionTextLocaleValueLookup to be anything but null.** I can retrieve other objects from the context just fine, and I have verified that DefaultSectionTextLocaleValueLookupId is not null at least some of the time.

My OnModelBuilding() contains the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LocaleValueLookup>()
    .ToTable("LocaleValueLookup")
    .HasKey(lvl => lvl.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<LocaleValueLookup>().Property(lvl => lvl.Id).IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<SectionType>()
    .ToTable("SectionType")
    .HasKey(st => st.EnumId);
modelBuilder.Entity<SectionType>().Property(st => st.EnumId).IsRequired();
```

A couple of other points:

- I would prefer not to have a SectionType collection on the LocaleValueLookup object. LocaleValueLookup is a low-level class that a lot of other classes depend on, so to include a collection property on LocaleValueLookup for every other class that references it will make for an unwieldy class with a lot of collections on it that I don't need from a domain perspective.
- I would prefer to do the mapping setup in DbContext.OnModelCreating() rather than using attributes on my model objects

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your foreign key is nullable so that means an optional -> many relationship.

Could you try something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SectionType>()
    .HasOptional(opt => opt.DefaultSectionTextLocaleValueLookup)
    .WithMany() // no navigation on the other side
    .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.DefaultSectionTextLocaleValueLookupId);
```

If you were to write a query like this you should get a value back:

```
var query = 
    from st in db.SectionTypes
    where st.EnumId == 12345
    select new
    {
        SectionType = st,
        LocaleValue = st.DefaultSectionTextLocaleValueLookup
    };
```

It will only be non-null if the foreign key has a value, obviously.

Comment: I get an error doing it that way: Invalid column name 'LocaleValueLookup_Id'. I would have thought that the HasForeignKey call would have handled that. The SQL being run is this: SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[EnumId] AS [EnumId], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[DefaultSectionTextLocaleValueLookupId] AS [DefaultSectionTextLocaleValueLookupId], 
    [Extent1].[LocaleValueLookup_Id] AS [LocaleValueLookup_Id]
    FROM [dbo].[SectionType] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 3 = [Extent1].[EnumId]

Comment: Did you remove the [ForeignKey] attribute from the entity?

Comment: Yes I did; there are no [ForeignKey] annotations on the SectionType table.

Comment: Not sure why your solution didn't work originally, but when I started a new project from scratch, it worked just fine.